# Shirt with Cleaners Tag on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, cleaning

Is one allowed to remove (by tearing) a cleaners' tag from his/her shirt on Shabbos?

Answer (score 6):

I have a Book called The 39 Melachos, it says you should not remove as it is a form of ripping (pg.1407)

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to find sources but off the cuff it would seem to be permitted provided one does not tear through letters. Removing manufacturers tags may be a bigger problem.

Comment: What if you need it off the tail instead of the cuff? :)

Comment: Actually I was referring to those left in button holes on the shirt.

Comment: I'm sure that @Yirmeyahu will find sources that say the following: don't tear the letters, and try to do it in a different way (shinui) than you normally tear things - then it's permissible.

Answer (score 2):

In the Shabbos Home it brings Reb Moshe Feinstein allowed going out with tags attached by Staples on Shabbos as it is Mevutal(SECONDARY?) to the clothing if one forgot to remove it before Shabbos. Based on Conjecture I am guessing removal would not be allowed according to him. although  Reb Simcha Bunim Cohem In the Shabbos Home Volume 2 allows removing the Price Tags.

Comment: Once again, please provide exact sources (and links whenever possible).

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize I put it at the end and not the begining